# Compile BlueZ without updating glib

Tags: compilation

I try to compile Bluez 5.33, but after a try to configure the package, the error message `configure: error: GLib >= 2.28 is required` appears.

But the problem is, i am not allowed to update or install anything on this machine. How can i compile BlueZ 5.33 without updating GLib?

Comment: By executing `./configure -help` i found this option: `LIBS        libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l<library>` so is it possible to point at the newer version of glib which is on my usb-stick, and then compile without error?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a newer version of GLib for a reason, it won't compile with an older version. You either build against a newer version of GLib or you stay with an older version of BlueZ.

**ps:** By the way, if you can't install anything on the machine, why could you use a newer version of BlueZ?

Comment: I don't want to install BlueZ, i just want to compile it.